# Angularjs: $routeChangeStart custom property coming as undefined on $location.path

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am using custom property in **$routeProvider** to check if the login is required or not and checking it at **$routeChangeStart** event. It is working fine on normal URL change but if I change the URL with **$location.path** then **custom property** is coming as undefined. Anybody know how to get custom property even with k$location.path

```
 $routeProvider.when('/result', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/result.html',
                controller: 'ResultCtrl',
                data: {
                    requireLogin: true
                }
            });
 $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        var requireLogin = false;
        if (next['data']) {
            requireLogin = next.data.requireLogin
        }
```

on normal redirect(using anchor href) **next.data.requireLogin** is working. But if I change the URL with **$locaion.path** it is coming as undefined.

Thanks,
Udesh

Comment: You had to use a path or query parameter to be able to get the value from an url redirect. Custom parameter are only passed from an angular state change with href or $state.go

Comment: But this parameter I cann't pass as query parameter...

Comment: Where do you need $location.path and why aren't you using another method like $state.go or sth?

Comment: try with $state.current.data.requireLogin on controller

Comment: I was setting the path like `$location.path('/result')` changing it to `$location.path('result')` did the trick....

Answer (score 1):

Probably your **path** you set via **$location.path** is wrong? I can't find any problems finding the custom **data** object if the **path**. If the **path** is doesn't match of one of the routes - well I get an **undefined** exception. I'd add a null check for **next** as well.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m0hUS8XceoQl7xKYOGnL?p=preview)

```
if (next && next['data'])
```

Comment: Great! thanks man... I was setting the path like

`$location.path('/result')`

changing it to 

`$location.path('result')`

did the trick....

Answer (score 1):

Issue was in the way I was setting $location.path(). I was setting the path like

```
$location.path('/result')
```

changing it to

```
$location.path('result')
```

did the trick....

Everywhere it is documented with **'/'** only... Not sure which one is the correct way but it solved my problem.. Thanks :)